# trouble to trigger Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, helper

is there any way to do trigger from Jenkins job build as(folder) to Jenkins job build as( pipeline) ?

I need to trigger from configure in said  Jenkins job  .

I can do trigger from project job build as( pipeline)  to project job build as( pipeline)  but any  job build as(folder) I can't .

could any one  please help me and explain why and how I can do trigger

Note : I'm admin in Jenkins .